# Nginx + uWsgi + Django strange json response behavior

Tags: python, django, json, nginx, uwsgi

Some tech specifications:

- CentOS 6.0
- uWSGI 0.9.9.2
- Nginx 1.0.5
- Django 1.3.1

uWSGI:

```
    [uwsgi]
    socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
    master = true
    processes = 5
    uid = xx
    gid = xx
    env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=xx.settings
    module = django.core.handlers.wsgi:WSGIHandler()
    post-buffering = 8192
    harakiri = 30
    harakiri-verbose = true
    disable-logging = true
    logto = /var/log/xx.log
    vacuum = true
    optimize = 2
```

JSON serializer:

```
class LazyEncoder(simplejson.JSONEncoder, json.Serializer):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Promise):
            return force_unicode(obj)
        if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
            u_value = force_unicode(obj)
            if u'.' in u_value:
                return float(u_value)
            return int(u_value)
        return super(lazy_encoder, self).default(obj)
```

JSON HttpResponse:

```
class JsonResponse(HttpResponse):
    status_code = 200
    json_status_code = 200
    message = _('OK')

    def __init__(self, json={}, *args, **kwargs):
        mimetype = kwargs.pop('mimetype', 'application/json')
        if not 'status' in json:
            json['status'] = {'code': self.json_status_code, 'message': self.message}
    super(JsonResponse, self).__init__(LazyEncoder(indent=settings.DEBUG and 4 or None, separators=settings.DEBUG and (', ', ': ') or (',', ':')).encode(json), mimetype=mimetype, *args, **kwargs)
```

I have a few subclasses of JsonResponse with other json_status_code and message.

View:

```
....
if application.status == Application.STATUS_REMOVED:
    return JsonApplicationSuspendedResponse()
....
return JsonResponse()
```

***PROBLEM:***

Even when the application status is changing it happens that I receives old json lest say for  3 - 4 seconds and then it returning JsonApplicationSuspendedResponse() correctly.

I checked the database application status update takes place immediately,
also noticed that if I reboot uWSGI and send request response is correct and the opposite situation happens. Second request after status change can have old json.

It looks as if they write the response for few sencods and had a problem with her ​​refresh (Cache is disabled).

Any ideas where it might be the problem ?

The same code works fine on Apache2 and mod_wsgi

**fixed**

This was a really stupid bug, in JsonResponse I had:

```
def __init__(self, json={}, *args, **kwargs):
```

part **json={}** is quite important here, JsonResponse and each subclass of JsonResponse after init shared initial dict and its contents, so the answer looked like a did not change.

```
def __init__(self, json=None, *args, **kwargs):
    mimetype = kwargs.pop('mimetype', 'application/json')
    if not json:
        json = {}
    if not 'status' in json:
        json['status'] = {'code': self.json_status_code, 'message': self.message}
```

**Thanks for your time**

Comment: Try adding a timestamp variable in your GET request.

Comment: I tried this, does not work I think is something with server-side

Comment: The [uwsgi nginx module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUwsgiModule) has several directives for controlling caching. It's unlikely that's your problem, as far as I know caching is not enabled by default.

Comment: I tend to blame uwsgi by default for such things, it's really buggy.  Try gunicorn, or uwsgi 0.9.6.8 (thats the best version i've found)

Comment: Please answer to your question and validate it.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried disabling the python optimizer (remove the optimize option from the uWSGI config file)?

Even if it looks like more a js/html/client issue some object can make some sort of mess with optimizations enabled. And please do not follow silly advise like downgrading to unsupported more than 1-years-old versions.

Comment: I have removed optimizer from uWSGI config file and clenup all *.pyo, *.pyc files, but nothing has changed

Comment: so it is caching problem for sure. Can you try putting uWSGI behind apache instead of nginx ? (you can add mod_uwsgi along mod_wsgi without problems). In this way we can understand where the problem is.

Comment: ...and another test you can do is directly asking nginx for the json view via curl, so you can be sure thet browser caching will not came into play. Have you tried with mod_wsgi both in eambedded and daemon mode ? damon_mode is more similar to the uWSGI approach

Comment: Now its Nginx -> uWsgi (Emperor mode) -> Django, on the test machine I have Apache2 -> mod_wsgi -> Django, I tried testing through urllib, also I have added a timestamp to each request (http://example.com/?20110927122345), but response still looks like 'cached'. I will try apache2 and I will let you know

Comment: sorry, forgot to suggest another test. If you re-enable uWSGI logging you will be able to see if the json request go through it or stop at nginx.